How to display Outlook.mailItem.HTMLBody in webBrowser.DocumentText?
Yes, like this:
webBrowser1.DocumentText = selectedMail.HTMLBody;

The problem is that there might be a selectedMail with one or multiple images in the body but will not be shown in the webBrowser control.
Is it possible to show the Body just as I can see it in Outlook?
(for context: mails have to be classified by a user through this UI, the human classification and mail attributes are inserted in a Data Base)
I added the answer below.

Let me first ask you, do you know how the cid: URI scheme works? and are you familiar with MIME multipart messages?

Not really :(. I imagine I have to search the img tags in the HTML and replace them with the right source... but I'm not really familiar with the syntax :(

go and google on some articles like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499904/getting-image-from-email

getting attachments from outlook https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339146/getting-attachments-from-outlook

Thanks,  I got more or less the idea. I ended using the mind map in the answer I added below. Have a good day.

This is the structure:

First set in disk a path where to download the image files.

Download the image files from the email attachments in such path.

Modify the HTMLBody of the mail replacing the src attribute from the image tags using the path where we have the images saved.

???

Profit.


//Sorry I don't add code. But thats the idea.
I'll add code:
Point 1)
private string image_path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "img_temp");

// Create the directory if it doesn't exist
Directory.CreateDirectory(image_path);



Point 2)
// Check for attachments and add them to the attachment list
foreach (Outlook.Attachment attachment in selectedMail.Attachments)
{
  if (IsImageAttachment(attachment))
  {
    //save image attachment in temp folder
    attachment.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(image_path, attachment.FileName));
    
  }
}


// Helper method to check if an attachment is an image
private bool IsImageAttachment(Outlook.Attachment attachment)
{
  // Check if the attachment is embedded and has a valid image extension
  return attachment.Type == Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue &&
    (attachment.FileName.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
       attachment.FileName.EndsWith(".jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
       attachment.FileName.EndsWith(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
       attachment.FileName.EndsWith(".gif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}


Point 3)
using HtmlAgilityPack;

// Load the HTML document
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(selectedMail.HTMLBody);
// Select all img tags
var imgNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");


if (imgNodes != null)
{
  foreach (var imgNode in imgNodes)
  {
    // Get the value of the src attribute
    var srcAttributeValue = imgNode.GetAttributeValue("src", "");
    
    // Extract the image file name from the src attribute
    var fileName = srcAttributeValue.Split('@')[0].Replace("cid:", "");
    
    // Replace the src attribute with the path to the image on your system
    var imagePath = Path.Combine(image_path, fileName);// Change this path to the directory where your images are located
    
    imgNode.SetAttributeValue("src", imagePath);
  }
}

// Get the modified HTML content
var modifiedHtml = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

webBrowser1.DocumentText = modifiedHtml;



